# How can I delete more than 100 messages at once?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I know I can't delete more than 100 with a bot, but can I start the script over to delete more?
This is my current code:

```js
const CLEAR_MESSAGES = '!clearmessages';

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'mytoken';

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('!clearmessages to run...');
  bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content == CLEAR_MESSAGES) {

      if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
        message.channel.fetchMessages()
          .then(messages => {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
            messagesDeleted = messages.array().length;

            message.channel.sendMessage("Number of deleted messages: "+messagesDeleted);
            console.log('Number of deleted messages: '+messagesDeleted)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('error.');
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }
  });
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can't delete more than 100 messages at once with `bulkDelete()`, but you can check and delete messages as long as there are any left. When the messages become older than two weeks you need to delete them one by one.
You can use a recursive asynchronous function that runs until there are no messages left. Keep in mind that in this way you'll delete **all** the messages in the channel.

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content == CLEAR_MESSAGES) {
    let messagesDeleted = await clearChannel(message.channel);

    message.channel.sendMessage("Number of deleted messages: " + messagesDeleted);
    console.log('Number of deleted messages: ' + messagesDeleted)
  }
});

async function clearChannel(channel, n = 0, old = false) {
  let collected = await channel.fetchMessages();
  if (collected.size > 0) {
    if (old) {
      for (let msg of collected.array()) {
        await msg.delete();
        n++;
      }
    } else {
      let deleted = await channel.bulkDelete(100, true);
      if (deleted.size < collected.size) old = true;
      n += deleted;
    }

    return n + await clearChannel(channel, old);
  } else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something  like this would repeat the cycle 4 times deleting 50 messages each time

```
let msgs = 0;
bot.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('!clearmessages to run...');
   bot.on('message', async message => {
      if (message.content == CLEAR_MESSAGES) {


         for (let index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
            if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
               await message.channel.fetchMessages()
                  .then(async  messages => {
                     await message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
                     messagesDeleted = messages.array().length;

                     msgs = msgs + messagesDeleted;
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                     console.log('error.');
                     console.log(err);
                  });
            }
         }
         console.log(`Total number of messages deleted ${msgs}`);
         message.channel.sendMessage(`Total number of messages deleted ${msgs}`);
      }
   });
});
```